# How do I deploy my docker-compose project using Terraform?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, terraform

I've looked all over and can't find a coherent resource that describes how to do this straightforwardly. I have a project like so:

```
./
 |-src/
 |--..
 |--Dockerfile
 |-docker-compose.yaml
```

A terraform config file like this:

```
variable "do_token" {}

# Configure the DigitalOcean Provider
provider "digitalocean" {
  token = "${var.do_token}"
}

# Create a web server
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  # ...
}
```

I want to be able to do something like

```
provider "digitalocean" {
    ip = <my-ip>
    # docker-compose up ?
}
```

My compose file sets up the application architecture properly. I just want a way to deploy that to a given box somewhere on digital ocean (via ip preferably) and the run `docker-compose up`. How can I do this?

Comment: docker-compose is a development tool; use Swarm for production, not compose.

Answer (score 25):

#### Provisioners

Terraform has [provisioners](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html) which allow you to copy files and execute scripts on resource creation.

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  # ...

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "compose-app/"
    destination = "/app"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "cd /app",
      "docker-compose up",
    ]
  }
}
```

The [Chef provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/chef.html) can also be used with a [compose cookbook](https://github.com/sboschert/chef-cookbook-docker_compose)

#### Docker

Terraform has a plain [Docker provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/index.html) but doesn't manage Compose or Swarm definitions out of the box so you would need to define your compose environment piece by piece in [volumes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/volume.html), [networks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/network.html), [images](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/image.html), [containers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/container.html)).

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://droplet:2375/"
}
resource "docker_image" "myapp" {
  name = "me/myapp:1.0.0"
}
resource "docker_container" "myapp" {
  name = "myapp"
  image = "${docker_image.myapp.latest}"
  ports {
    internal = 1234
    external = 1234
  }
}
```

#### Kubernetes

For deploying real world apps With Terraform you are probably better of using the [Kubernetes provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) that will let you set up a [replication controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) to run [pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) that are accessed as [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) on Docker. This will require running a Kubernetes cluster and writing the Kubernetes definition, [Kompose](http://kompose.io/) can help converting from Docker Compose.

Comment: Docker provider doesn't seem to work out of the box. You need to generate the certificates first. Any experience running it on AWS?

Comment: a file provisioner is my choice here