# How can I create Docker certificates when running on EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ansible, terraform

I'm using Terraform to spin up an EC2 instance. Then, I run an Ansible playbook to configure the instance and run `docker-compose`.

I noticed that Ansible's `docker_service` requires `key_path` and `cert_path` to be set when running against a remote Docker daemon. I'd like to use a remote connection, as the Docker images required have already been built locally as part of my CI/CD process.

How can I generate the cert and key for an EC2 instance?

I found this question: [How do I deploy my docker-compose project using Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983827/how-do-i-deploy-my-docker-compose-project-using-terraform), but it uses `remote-exec` from Terraform and assumes the project source will exist on the remote machine.

There are a few questions which provide reasonable workflows, but they all involve using `docker-machine` which is not quite what I want.

Comment: Ansible already has an ssh path to run commands as root on the target system; why would you need the (dangerous) Docker remote API?

Comment: @DavidMaze -- that's not quite what I'm interested in. I'd like to run docker-compose on the local machine and have it set up its stack on the remote. This can be done by setting DOCKER_HOST and a few other environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found it:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

This document describes how to create the CA, server key-cert, and client key-cert.

And, the following document describes how to make a cert using Ansible:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/openssl_certificate_module.html